# extract columns with Bash or awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a folder with 1000 text files. I would like to extract fourth and fifth columns from each file and save it to an another folder with the same filenames. How can I do this with `awk` or `Bash`?

Comment: You should at least put an example of the kind of file that you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 5):

Since you haven't specified about the field separator, I am assuming as the default(space) field separator.

```
awk '{print $4,$5>"/tmp/another_directory/"FILENAME}' *
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU find and GNU sed, assuming space separated columns and the files to process are in the current directory:

```
mkdir tmp/
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 -l /bin/sh -c 'sed -r "s/([^ ] *){3}([^ ]) *([^ ]*).*/\2 \3/" "$1" > "tmp/$1"' ''
```

Note the last pair of single quotes are important, they're a placeholders so the filename gets passed correctly to `sh`. The processed files are saved to `tmp/` in the current directory.